# Is it faster to query CouchDB via an adapter instead of REST?

Tags: python, database, performance, couchdb

Let's say I have some data in a CouchDB database. The overall size is about 100K docs.

I have a _design doc which stores a 'get all entities' view.

Assuming the requests are done on a local machine against a local database:

1. via curl: `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1/mydb/_design/myexample/_view/all`
2. via [Couchdbkit](http://couchdbkit.org/docs/gettingstarted.html): `entities = Entity.view('mydb/all’)`

Does `1` have to perform any additional calculations compared to `2` (JSON encoding/decoding, HTTP request parsing, etc.) and how can that affect the performance of querying 'all' entities from the database?

I guess that directly querying the database (option 2) should be faster than wrapping request/response into JSON, but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the API covers, Couchdbkit uses the [`restkit` package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/restkit), which is a REST library.

In other words, Couchdbkit is a pythonic API to the CouchDB REST API, and will do the same amount of work as using the REST API yourself.